# Linear Systems and Linear Transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, normed-spaces

I want to confirm my attempt to see if I am on the right track. The question is as follows.

> > Show that the operator norm of a inear transformation $T$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ satisfies $$||T||=\text{max}_{|\vec{x}|=1}|T(\vec{x})|=\text{sup}_{\vec{x}\neq \vec{0}}\frac{|T(\vec{x})|}{|\vec{x}|}$$

What I understand:

- Operator norm of $T$ is defined by $||T||=\text{max}_{|\vec{x}|\leq 1}|T(\vec{x})|$.
- For $S,T\in L(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $\vec{x}\in\mathbb{R}$,
- 1) $||T(\vec{x})||\leq ||T||\cdot ||\vec{x}||$
- 2) $||TS||\leq||T||||S||$
- 3) $||T^k|| \leq ||T||^k$ for $k = 1, 2, \dots$

Understanding this I did the following.

> Let $T$ be a linear transformation on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Seeking to prove $||T||=\text{max}|T(\vec{x})|=\text{sup}_{\vec{x}\neq \vec{0}}\frac{|T(\vec{x})|}{|\vec{x}|}$ is true, let $|T(\vec{x})|= ||T||\cdot |\vec{x}|$. By definition of operator norm of $T$, $||T||=\text{max}_{|\vec{x}|\leq 1}|T(\vec{x})|$. Now $\text{sup}_{\vec{x}\neq\vec{0}}\frac{|T(\vec{x})|}{|\vec{x}|}=\frac{||T||\cdot|\vec{x}|}{|\vec{x}|}= ||T|| = \text{max}_{|x|\leq 1}|T(\vec{x})|$. QED.

Granted, I am not sure if I can assume $|T(\vec{x})|= ||T||\cdot |\vec{x}|$ since $|T(\vec{x})| \leq ||T||\cdot |\vec{x}|$.

---

Thank You so much for taking the time to read this. I thank you in advance for any assistance or guidance you may provide.

Answer (score 0):

(1)For any $x$ with $||x||\leq 1$ there exists $y$ with $||y||=1$ and $|T(x)|\leq |T(y)|$. PROOF.If $x=0$ let $y$ be any vector of norm $1$ because $T(0)=0$. If $ 0<||x||\leq 1 $ let y=x/||x|| (Because $||x||\leq 1 \implies |T(y)|=|T(x)|/||x|| \geq |T(x)|$.) .....................(2) Therefore  $$||T||= \sup \{|T(x)| : ||x||\leq 1\} \leq \sup \{|T(y)| : ||y||=1\}=V.$$ But by the def'n of $||T||$ we have $||T||\geq V$....Therefore $$T=V.$$.(3)Let A= $\{x/||x|| : x\neq 0\}$ and let $B=\{y :||y=1||\}$ . Then $$A=B.$$PROOF.If $z=x/||x|| \in A$ then $||z|| =1 $ so $ z\in B$. If $ y \in B$ then $y=y/||y|| \in A$     .......................(4) Therefore, because $T$ is linear, $$\sup  \{|T(x)/||x|| : x\neq 0\}=$$  $$ \sup \{|T(x/||x||)| : x\neq 0\}=$$ $$ \sup  \{|T(y)| :y \in  A\}=$$ $$   \sup \{|T(y)| :y \in B \}=U=||T||.$$. NOTES (5).I have written |T(x)| for ||T(x)|| throughout this, which could be edited if someone feels like it.I take it that the range of $T$ is $R^m$ for some positive integer  $m$....(6) The fact that $T$ attains its norm,that is |T(y)|=||T|| for some $y \in B$, is another matter, which depends on the compactness of $B$ and the continuity of the function $f(y)=|T(y)|$ for $y \in B$.